# how to use native javascript methods in Vue created() hook?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i am creating simple Vue.js application i am using Vue cli 3, I want to use native DOM method, to watch scroll behavior, Everything works fine, but the problem occurs when i am changing  router view, and then console  throws error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined`  what i am doing wrong?

```js
 created() {
    /* contorl slider scroll height and give navbar fixed positiom */
    window.addEventListener("scroll", ()=>{
    var firstbox = document.getElementById("sliderBox");
      if (window.scrollY >= firstbox.scrollHeight) {
        this.isVisiable = true
      } else {
        this.isVisiable = false
      }
    
});
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be a honest, I could not understand exactly what your problem is, but i think you are using `addEventListener` not right way, if you want to use it in `created()` hook also you need to destroy it after route changed, in Vue2 you can use `destroyed()` hook, but in Vue3 you can use `unmounted()`, hope this will help you

```js
  
  methods:{
  yourFunction() {
      var firstbox = document.getElementById("sliderBox");
      if (window.scrollY >= firstbox.scrollHeight) {
        //do something
      } else {
        //do something
      }
    }
  }

  
  created() {

    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.yourFunction);
  },

  unmounted(){
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.yourFunction)
  }
```

.